# read a string from the file till we get '\n' character or EOF in c/c++

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to open two files and and save those strings into third file which are present in the first file but not in the second file.
for that i have to read line by line string (i.e till i arrive at the next line character).
But for the last line of the file i don't have '\n' in the end because there is EOF .so, please help me in reading all the string of a file and store then in a character array..

code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
FILE *f1ptr,*f2ptr,*f3ptr;
f1ptr=fopen("1stfile.txt","r");
f3ptr=fopen("3rdfile.txt","w");
char arr1[100],arr2[100];
while(fscanf(f1ptr," %[^\n]",arr1)!=EOF)    
    {
    f2ptr=fopen("2ndfile.txt","r");
    int flag=1;
    while(fscanf(f2ptr," %[^\n]",arr2)!=EOF)
        {
        if(strcmp(arr1,arr2) ==0)
            {
            flag=0;//flag=0 means i will not store this string into file
            }
        }
    fclose(f2ptr);
    if(flag)
        fprintf(f3ptr,"%s\n",arr1);
    }
return 0;
}
```

my files are as follows 
**1st file**

```
 Minimum Points To Reach Destination
 Maximum Index
 Maximum of minimum for every window size
 Find Prime numbers in a range
 Largest Number formed from an Array
 Find sum of different corresponding bits for all pairs
 Rearrange an array with O(1) extra space
 Return two prime numbers
 Sorting Elements of an Array by Frequency 
 A Simple Fraction 
 QuickSort on Doubly Linked List
 Reorder List
 Binary Tree to DLL
 Tree from Postorder and Inorder
```

**2nd file**

```
 Maximum Index
 Find Prime numbers in a range
 Rearrange an array with O(1) extra space
 Return two prime numbers
 Sorting Elements of an Array by Frequency
```

Comment: fopen() and fclose() of 2nd file should be done once.  Use rewind() to move the file cursor to the top.

Comment: Always check if fopen() was successful.

Comment: Please provide a sample of inputs and what the expected output should be.

Comment: Why not read 2nd file and put the strings in a double char array: char arr2[100][100];  Would 100 lines be plenty?

Comment: using `fgets` would be safer than using `fscanf` as you can specify how large your string buffers are.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read lines (there may be a better way in C++; I don't know that language).

Comment: @pmg why do you think the code is C++ not C? stdio.h is definitely a C include

Comment: There is no need for this line: `using namespace std;`  That's for C++.

Comment: @pmg true - remove that line (which isn't even needed) and the code is pure C though.

Comment: Please help me now . Now i have also provided both files

Comment: Your approach is very inefficient. Because for each line in file1 you read all lines of file2. It may be OK for small files but for bigger files it's going to get very slow.

Comment: @Michael Walz can you  suggest me some good algorithm for that?

Comment: @Nishantsharma 1. read one of the files into memory, that's easy. 2. If you're a bit more courageous, you can sort the lines in memory and do a binary search instead of a linear search. Or read the file directly into a binary tree; but this solution is not good if the lines in the file are already sorted, then you need a balanced binary tree which is harder to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `rewind()`.

```
f1ptr=fopen("1stfile.txt","r");
//Check f1ptr is not NULL.
f2ptr=fopen("2ndfile.txt","r");
//Check f2ptr is not NULL.
f3ptr=fopen("3rdfile.txt","w");
//Check f3ptr is not NULL.
char arr1[100],arr2[100];

while(fgets(arr1, sizeof arr1, f1ptr) )   
{
    int flag=1;
    rewind(f2ptr);  //Moves file pointer to the top.
    while(fgets(arr2,sizeof arr2, f2ptr))
    {
        if(strcmp(arr1,arr2) ==0)
        {
           flag=0;//flag=0 means i will not store this string into file
           break;  //Break out of the loop if 2 files have the same line.
        }
    }
    if(flag)
       fprintf(f3ptr,"%s",arr1);  //No need to print newline. Its already there.
  }
  fclose(f1ptr);
  fclose(f2ptr);
  fclose(f3ptr);
```

If you do `man fgets`, here is a part of the description:`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So newline char gets added to the string but not EOF.

Answer (score 0):

The following could work. If you use fgets, the last line will be add '\n'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
//using namespace std;
int main()
{
    FILE *f1ptr,*f2ptr,*f3ptr;
    f1ptr=fopen("1stfile.txt","r");
    f3ptr=fopen("3rdfile.txt","w");
    char arr1[100],arr2[100];

    while (fgets(arr1, 100, f1ptr) != NULL) {
        f2ptr=fopen("2ndfile.txt","r");
        int flag=1;
        while (fgets(arr2, 100, f2ptr)!=NULL) {
            if (strcmp(arr1,arr2) ==0) {
                flag=0;  //flag=0 means i will not store this string into file   
            }
        }
        fclose(f2ptr);
        if (flag)
            fprintf(f3ptr,"%s",arr1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```